# How to get a value from nested arrays? JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, jsonparser

I have a problem with parsing tickets. There is a JSON link that contains the following data:
[json file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znd44i86aqfjnik/json.html?dl=0)

```
{"success":true,"data":{"AAE":{"2":{"price":48973,"airline":"AF","flight_number":1745,"departure_at":"2018-09-04T18:45:00Z","return_at":"2018-09-14T07:15:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-02T06:57:21Z"},"3":{"price":67240,"airline":"TP","flight_number":1235,"departure_at":"2018-09-04T07:15:00Z","return_at":"2018-09-14T07:15:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-02T06:57:21Z"}},"AAH":{"1":{"price":34049,"airline":"LH","flight_number":1453,"departure_at":"2018-09-30T09:05:00Z","return_at":"2018-10-02T07:40:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T11:37:06Z"},"2":{"price":35838,"airline":"LH","flight_number":1453,"departure_at":"2018-09-30T09:05:00Z","return_at":"2018-10-02T11:39:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T11:37:06Z"}},"AAL":{"1":{"price":23258,"airline":"KL","flight_number":904,"departure_at":"2018-12-08T18:00:00Z","return_at":"2018-12-15T06:00:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T13:27:58Z"},"2":{"price":21867,"airline":"AF","flight_number":1745,"departure_at":"2018-12-08T20:00:00Z","return_at":"2018-12-15T18:15:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T13:27:58Z"},"3":{"price":30639,"airline":"AF","flight_number":1145,"departure_at":"2018-12-08T09:45:00Z","return_at":"2018-12-15T06:00:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T13:27:58Z"}},"AAQ":{"0":{"price":5354,"airline":"FV","flight_number":5515,"departure_at":"2018-09-16T04:20:00Z","return_at":"2018-10-04T12:40:00Z","expires_at":"2018-08-31T20:53:40Z"},"1":{"price":8590,"airline":"FV","flight_number":5515,"departure_at":"2018-09-16T04:20:00Z","return_at":"2018-10-04T15:05:00Z","expires_at":"2018-08-31T20:53:40Z"},"2":{"price":13702,"airline":"U6","flight_number":79,"departure_at":"2018-10-04T11:20:00Z","return_at":"2018-10-10T12:40:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-03T06:47:01Z"}},"AAR":{"1":{"price":24418,"airline":"OK","flight_number":905,"departure_at":"2018-09-19T22:10:00Z","return_at":"2018-09-25T09:35:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-02T21:16:33Z"},"2":{"price":20805,"airline":"AY","flight_number":712,"departure_at":"2018-09-19T11:50:00Z","return_at":"2018-09-25T16:55:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-02T21:16:33Z"},"3":{"price":36316,"airline":"BT","flight_number":425,"departure_at":"2018-09-19T09:45:00Z","return_at":"2018-09-25T09:35:00Z","expires_at":"2018-09-02T21:16:33Z"}},
```

My code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

request = Request("http://api.link")
response_body = urlopen(request).read()

tickets = json.loads(response_body)

for item in tickets['data']:
    price = item['AAL']['1']['price']
    print(price)
```

I tried various options to get the value of price, but nothing happened.

Help me get this value

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems to me that you should not be looping through values with a "for". Try doing something like tickets['data']['AAL']['1']['price'] directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try this with the raw data you (finally) added in your question—although still not as text as I suggested. Instead I manually typed in (and fixed the formatting of) the snippet that was shown in the image you originally posted.

Regardless, the following should at least be close and shows you how to access the various parts of the data structure:

```
response_body = '''
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "AAL": {
            "1": {
                "price": 53411,
                "airline": "KL",
                "flight_number": 904,
                "departure_at": "2018-08-31T17:00:002",
                "return_at": "2018-09-01T18:20:002",
                "expires_at": "2018-08-31T17:00:OOZ"
            },
            "2": {
                "price": 56035,
                "airline": "BT",
                "flight_number": 429,
                "departure_at": "2018-08-31T15:25:002",
                "return_at": "2018-09-01To6:35:002",
                "expires_at": "2018-08-31T15:25:OOZ"
            }
        },
        "AAQ": {
            "0": {
                "price": 6242,
                "airline": "DP",
                "flight_number": 147,
                "departure_at": "2018-09-15T21:00:002",
                "return_at": "2018-10-05T12:40:002",
                "expires_at": "2018-09-03T13:18:222"
            }
        }
    }
}'''
```

Code to process the data:

```
import json

tickets = json.loads(response_body)

for airport, flights in tickets['data'].items():
    print('airport:', airport)
    for id, flight in flights.items():
        print('  id:', id)
        print('    airline:', flight['airline'])
        print('    flight_number:', flight['flight_number'])
        print('    price:', flight['price'])  # Here's how to get the price.
```

Comment: I looked. it seems even more than I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: silenoz: Glad to hear you found it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is casting item as a string in the for loop. So when you're calling ['1'] it is throwing an error, where as if you set it to an integer, i.e. [1] it would bring back the second char of the key, in this case 'A' from 'AAL'. This will work if you mod it to fit your needs.

```
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

request = Request("http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&page=1&      token=77e84779fa444c14806f022f6c41b7fe")
response_body = urlopen(request).read()

tickets = json.loads(response_body)

for item in tickets['data']:
    if item == 'AAL':
        price = tickets['data'][item]['1']['price']

print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that these "1" and "2" are items of `list` not `dict`. And you need to iterate through them. Try to handle like here:

```
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

request = Request("http://api.link")
response_body = urlopen(request).read()

tickets = json.loads(response_body)

for key, items in tickets['data'].items():
    for item in items:
        price = item['price']
        print(price)
```

Comment: "1" and "2" **aren't** items of a `list`.